# Using a semaphore instead of while loop. Is this good or bad?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have a process that runs in it's own thread and can be started/stopped without blocking.  This will eventually go into a Windows service, but I am setting this up in a console app for now until it is fully fleshed out.

After the call to Start(), I want the main program thread to block until Ctrl-C is pressed.  I know that this will work:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool keepGoing = true;

    var service = new Service();

    System.Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;

    System.Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        service.Stop();
        keepGoing = false; // Break the while loop below
    };

    service.Start();

    while( keepGoing )
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100); // 100 is arbitrary
    }

}
```

However, I find the flag and arbitrary sleep value bothersome.  I know that the CPU cost is practically 0 in the while loop, but I'd rather have a "hard" block that releases as soon as the Ctrl-C handler is done.  I devised the below, using a semaphore to block until the anonymous Ctrl-C handler is done:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var service = new Service();

    var s = new Semaphore(1, 1);

    System.Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;

    System.Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        service.Stop();
        s.Release(); // This will allow the program to conclude below
    };

    service.Start();

    s.WaitOne(); // This will not block
    s.WaitOne(); // This will block w/o CPU usage until the sempahore is released

}
```

Is this a bad design?  Is it overkill?  Is it dangerous?

**EDIT:**

I also hook up AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException as follows:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate {
  service.Stop();
  s.Release();
};
```

**EDIT the 2nd:**

I should note that it is crucial that the `Stop()` method get called on exit.  @Adam Ralph has a perfectly good pattern for a hybrid console/service, but didn't have this information when answering the Q.

Comment: If you can avoid the while loop I say it's worth pursuing.

Comment: For prototyping the latter is much of an improvement.  In a production application I would avoid the whole "CTRL + C" break idea.  Use a signal to kill the thread instead.  The way the signal is `Set()` depends on the other layers involved.  Just keep this in mind when designing your service.  Add a means, like a method that can be called to, in turn, call `Set()`.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Although this isn't a production application, if it *were*, wouldn't it be prudent to at least handle Ctrl-C gracefully in a non-interactive console app?  As it is, Ctrl-C will simply shut down the program without an opportunity to clean up before exiting.  Ultimately, I was simply wondering if the semaphore solution to the "while (flag) Thread.Sleep(...)" option.

Comment: You can so the same thing with an Event.  Semaphore would be more apropriate if you were waiting on multiple threads before shutdown, it's overkill for this case.  In general this is a good practice - avoid polling.

Comment: @Chris Simmons - Well, its an interesting idea and probably the best thing to do given that scenerio.  Personally, I would avoid using a console application as a service entirely.  There are a list of other problems that arise.  Services are designed to be long running, system restart-able without user intervention amongst other details.  So, ultimately I say use a service instead and avoid all those issues and other issues that will almost certainly come back to haunt you later.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Exactly. Once we found some problems with the standard  WaitHandle.WaitAll. It was expected that every thread would have been finished before the main thread of console ran on.But actually it didn't happen. So the best solution we could find was create an own semaphore class with a while loop and Thread.Sleep(1). There were no problems after that.

Comment: I would recommend using a `ManualResetEvent` rather than a `Semaphore`. Or a named `EventWaitHandle` if you have to communicate across processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a similar requirement in a few of our apps. They are Windows services, but for debugging we often want to run them as console apps. Moreover, we usually code new apps as Windows services fairly early on but often don't want to have to actually run them as a service until later, once we've proved the concept, etc.

This is the pattern we use:-

```
using (var service = new Service())
{
    if (Environment.UserInterActive)
    {
        service.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(service);
    }
}
```

Telling the thread to sleep infinitely might seem inefficient, but this is only for debugging scenarios and the redundant thread costs no CPU time, just some memory (about 1MB), which is mostly composed of the stack space allocated to the thread. The process can still be exited with Ctrl+C or by closing the command window.

-- EDIT --

If you find that `service.Dispose()` is not being called when Ctrl+C is pressed (i.e. a rude abort happens) and the call to `Dispose()` is crucial, then I guess you could explicitly do this like so:-

```
using (var service = new Service())
{
    if (Environment.UserInterActive)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) => service.Dispose();
        service.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(service);
    }
}
```

Note that `Stop()` should be encapsulated in `Dispose()`.

Comment: Doesn't this still suffer from the problem where, in a `UserInterActive` context, if the user were to attempt to stop the process (using Ctrl-C or window close), the `Stop()` method would not be called?  This is what I'm trying to accomplish in my example above.

Comment: In our services, calling the Stop method isn't crucial but I guess you could still subscribe to CancelKeyPress and do that explicitly. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I wasn't clear on this in the Q; sorry for that.  I edited mentioning this.